# How to pull items grouped and sorted by another table in Ecto?

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm new to Phoenix (coming from Ruby/Rails), and after digging around in the docs, I couldn't figure out how to represent this relatively straightforward SQL query in Ecto:

```
select d.*, t.doc_id, count(*) as cnt 
from taggings t, docs d 
where d.id = t.doc_id 
group by d.id, t.doc_id 
order by cnt desc 
limit 20;
```

This is what the next line will be, what I'm sending to the template:

```
top_docs = Repo.all(top_docs_query) |> Repo.preload(:tags) |> Repo.preload(:taggings)
```

What am I missing?

---

Edit after working with accepted answer:

**If you return the count, you will break preloading.** This messed me up for a while this morning. Preloading appears to only work if it's just a list of the structs.

Here's the final code that did what I wanted, based on the query above (replace App with your application..):

```
top_docs_query =
  from d in App.Doc,
  join: t in App.Tagging, on: [doc_id: d.id],
  group_by: [d.id, t.doc_id],
  order_by: [desc: count(t.id)],
  limit: 20
  # select: {d, t.doc_id, count(d.id)} <- This is what was breaking the preloading.


top_docs = Repo.all(top_docs_query) |> Repo.preload(:taggings) |> Repo.preload(:tags)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the job, but please note that I haven't tested this:

```
from t in Tagging,
  join: d in Doc, on: [id: t.doc_id],
  group_by: [d.id, t.doc_id],
  order_by: [desc: count(d.id)],
  limit: 20,
  select: {d, t.doc_id, count(d.id)}
```

Comment: See my notes in my edit to the question, especially about the select statement and preloading.